# Determine if JavaScript class extends another class

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

So suppose I had a class in Backbone:

```
var MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend( {} );
```

Using the instanceof operator I could check whether an instantiated object extended an object:

```
var instModel = new MyModel();
instModel instanceof MyModel; // true
instModel instanceof Backbone.Model; // true
```

I'd like to able to check inheritance without instantiating the object. Is there a means in JavaScript or Backbone to determine whether the uninstantiated class extends the object?  Since:

```
 MyModel instanceof Backbone.Model; // false
 MyModel instanceof Function; // true
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use instanceof like this:

```
MyModel.prototype instanceof Backbone.Model
```

This works because while there no instantiated instance of `MyModel`, you don't really care about it, you care about its prototype chain anyway, so you can just check its prototype inheritance.

Note, this will not work for the specific check of

```
MyModel.prototype instanceof MyModel
```

That might be fine depending on your use-case, but it you do want that to work, you have two options:

```
MyModel === MyModel && MyModel.prototype instanceof MyModel

// OR

Object.create(MyModel.prototype) instanceof MyModel
```

Comment: Good solution. I knew it had to be something simple.  Just to clarify for future readers, this misses one big case.  `MyModel.prototype instanceof MyModel` would fail.  So a robust production check would look like `(testModel !== ClassToCheck) && (testModel.prototype instanceof ClassToCheck)`

Comment: @stakolee True! I thought about adding a note about that and opted not to, but since you mentioned it, I've updated the answer with two options.

Answer (score 1):

You could try

```
Backbone.Model.prototype.isPrototypeOf(MyModel)
```

I'm not familiar with Backbone's inheritance model, but `instanceof` would assume that `Backbone.Model` is a classic JavaScript constructor, and check using its prototype. The advantage of `isPrototypeOf` is that you can specify the prototype directly rather than indirectly through a constructor.

Comment: Seems like this should be what I need, just need to hash through it a bit more in my actual code

Comment: Actually, I guess Backbone must perform inheritance in its own specific way, bypassing a case that isPrototypeOf would catch. The above example doesn't work in my tests.

Comment: It should be `.isPrototypeOf(MyModel.prototype)`.